# List comprehension ValueError: too many values to unpack

Tags: python

I have a process which generates 2-item lists as `[datestamp, timestamp]`.

if I put this into a list comprehension as:

```
[(ds,ts) for ds,ts in process]
```

my desired outcome is:

```
[(ds,ts), (ds,ts), (ds,ts)]
```

What I get is `ValueError: too many values to unpack`.

This is because the `for` loop iteration into the list returned by the process:

```
for ds,ts in [datestamp, timestamp]
```

does not assign `ds=datestamp`, `ts=timestamp`, but rather iterates across each letter ... if this worked it would give `(d,t)`, `(a,i)`, `(t,m)`, `(e,e)` etc

So I know what's wrong ... but not how to make this work! 
(and yeah, this does feel silly ... I know the answer will be real simple

Comment: Are you after `[(x[0],x[1]) for x in process]`? on each iteration you have a single list object with 2 items so you just need to index into the list

Comment: So you have a list containing two elements, and want to turn it into a tuple containing two elements? How about `my_tuple = tuple(my_list)`?

Comment: Please post the contents of `process`.

Comment: Try `[(ds,ts) for ds, ts in zip(datestamp, timestap)]`

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions. I subsequently decided on a completely different approach not involving this list comprehension issue.

Answer (score 5):

This works:

```
process = [[1,2],[3,4],[5,6]]
a = []
for ds, ts in process:
    print(ds, ts)
    a.append((ds, ts))
```

As well as

```
z = [(ds, ts) for (ds, ts) in process]
q = [(ds, ts) for ds, ts in process]
```

If you are getting a `'ValueError: too many values to unpack'` exception, process must be producing iterables that have more than two items.

Unwind the list comprehension and [Handle the exception](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/errors.html#handling-exceptions) - print something relevant in the except suite to see what might be going wrong, then work backwards to the source. something like

```
process = [[1,2],[3,4],[5,6], [7,8,9]]

a = []
try:
    for thing in process:
        ds, ts = thing
        a.append((ds, ts))
except ValueError as e:
    print(e, '\t', thing)
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to debug. There must be some items in your list that are not pairs as you expect.

One way you can find them would be:

```
problems = [(idx, value) for idx,value in enumerate(process) if len(value)!=2]
```

This will give you a list of the problem indexes and items in your list.

If that gives an error- for example, a `TypeError` because the `value` object has no `__len__` method- then change it to:

```
problems = [(idx, value) for idx,value in enumerate(process) if not hasattr(value, '__len__')]
```